# How to make console.log work in react native for android

Tags: android, react-native

Any pointers on how to see console logs while developing android application using react native would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the android emulator, open the app and press `F2`, then click `Debug in Chrome`. That should fire up a new window in Chrome, hit `F12` in that window to open up dev tools and you'll see the logs in the console.

Comment: I resolve the same problem. See https://medium.com/@vinceyuan/react-native-debugging-tools-3a24e4e40e4#5ad5

Answer (score 12):

You can see the log by opening a terminal and entering the following command:

```
adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V
```

This will show all React Native logged statements on any connected devices or emulators.