# Constructor is not called, but render is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have some React Native code within which I have the following React class:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, View, Text,  Platform } from 'react-native';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default class MyList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      console.log("In constructor!");
      //some other code
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("In componentWillMount!");
  }

  render() {
    console.log("In render method!");
        return ( 
        <ScrollView
          horizontal={true} 
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}
          onLayout={this._onScrollViewLayout}
          onScroll={this._onScroll}
          ref={SCROLLVIEW_REF}
          scrollEventThrottle={8}
        > 
         //some other code
         </ScrollView>

        );
  }
}
```

The problem is that only this is printed in the logs:

```
 ReactNativeJS: In render method!
```

Why can I not see the logging in either the `constructor` or `componentWillMount`, which should be called before the `render` method?

**EDIT**:

For logging, I'm using `react-native log-android`.

Comment: `Constructor` and `componentWillMount` are only called once (when the component is mounted). After that, everytime component update, these methods are not called but `render` is called. Are you saying that these methods are not called even when the component is mounted?

Comment: Ok, but the logging from those methods should still appear, right? Logging is a middleware that is in scope when the constructor is called, right?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem might be with `react-native log-android`

I just tested your code on Google Chrome and that seems to be working just fine.

Maybe this will help pinpoint whether the issue is with react-native log-android? 
[How to make console.log work in react native for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987532/how-to-make-console-log-work-in-react-native-for-android)